# Higher clock ram?

Tags: memory, clockspeed

My laptop (HP 6715s) mounts PC2-5300 200-PIN SODIMM ram. I want to buy some more.  Can I use higher clock ram on it:

- PC2-6400 ?
- DDR3-1333 (PC10600) ?

Is safe to assume that if the ram fits in the socket it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any DDR2 SODIMM memory in your laptop. If the motherboard does not support it, it will down-clock the ram to the motherboard's maximum supported frequency. It won't take DDR3, though - [the RAM would not fit in the slot.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg)

Comment: This reminded me of the epic fitting of a PCI-Express VGA card into an AGP slot. http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/7820/image4nqio8.jpg